# C++ Primer Exercise 2.41

Tags: c++

I'm stucked at 1 exercise which was at the end of the chapter 2 !  My problem with this exercise is that I can't figure out how to make logically loop to ask several times the input ! I wrote the code which ask twice for the input ! Previously with book provided header I did that task easy but that way didn't work anymore . So I'll give you the exercise and code and hope you can help me. And sorry for my English.

**Exercise**
Write program which will have a class in same place where you `main` function.
Write Code which will read several transaction with same Book Number and count each  transaction with that book number.

**My Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Data structure Code 
struct Sales_Data
{
std::string bookNo;
unsigned unit_sold;
double revenue;
};
int main()
{

Sales_Data data1,data2; //Data wich will hold input 
double price;           //Price per book used to calculate total revenue

// Checking if there was data input of book number units sold and price
if (std::cin>>data1.bookNo>>data1.unit_sold>>price)
{
    int cnt=1;  //Start Counter 
    data1.revenue=data1.unit_sold*price;// data1 calculating total revenue from price and unit_sold 

    while (std::cin>>data2.bookNo>>data2.unit_sold>>price)
    {
        data2.revenue=data2.revenue*price;

              //checking if book name is same
        if (data1.bookNo == data2.bookNo)
        {
            ++cnt; //Incrementing counter if they same
            unsigned totalCnt=data1.unit_sold+data2.unit_sold;
            double totalRevenue=data1.revenue+data2.revenue;
            //Print out result
            std::cout<<cnt<<data1.bookNo<<" "<<totalCnt<<" "<<totalRevenue<<" ";
            getchar();
            getchar();
            getchar();
            if (totalCnt != 0)

                std::cout<<totalCnt/totalRevenue;
            else 
                std::cout<<"(No Sales)"<<std::endl;
                return 0;
        }else{
            std::cerr<<"Book numbers isn't same"<<std::endl;
            return -1;
        }           
    }
}
return 0;          
}
```

And also wast sure why but the **revenue** gives me garbage number.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you init the `data2.revenue` before using it?

```
data2.revenue=data2.revenue*price;
```

To init `data2`, you could:

```
struct Sales_Data
{
    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned unit_sold;
    double revenue;

    Sales_Data(std::string s = "", unsigned u = 0, double r = 0)
        : bookNo(s), unit_sold(u), revenue(r) {}
};
```

or

```
Sales_Data data2 = { "a", 0, 0 };
```

or

```
Sales_Data data2;
data2.bookNo = "";
data2.unit_sold = 0;
data2.revenue = 0;
```

For multiple inputs:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std

int main()
{
    map<string, Sales_Data> count;
    Sales_Data data;

    while (cin >> data.bookNo >> data.unit_sold) { // <- this will allow you read multiple transactions

        if (map.find(data.bookNo) != count.end()) {
            count[data.bookNo].unit_sold += data.unit_sold;
            // and do some other thing.
        } else {
            count[data.bookNo] = data.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's declaration, not definition...  You could try `std::cout << data2.revenue << std::endl` here, and see what's the output.  It should be garbage.

Comment: sorry ! No it tells me that data member is not allowed to initialize

Comment: @AlexGreat See updates.

Comment: Yea it helps to initialize Thank . Dunno how i miss that explanation !

Comment: @AlexGreat Welcome to C++ :)

Comment: Do you know also what the problem in my code ! Why i cant do several inputs not just 2 like 10 - 15

Comment: What do you mean by several inputs?

Comment: To do input 5 times for exampl ! and calculate those 5 transaction for same book number ! In this code it only give me to do input 2 times

Comment: @AlexGreat Is this update what you need?

Comment: Thanks ! Im noob yet in C++ didnt got that far . But will write this in my note

Comment: Not Exactly this uptade what i want but it will be in my note

Comment: @AlexGreat I think the above code allows you to 1. get as many transactions as you want, and 2. group the same book number data together. :) hope it helps.